# Flutter: Tab key not working properly in flutter desktop when screen not maximised

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

Im developing for flutter desktop and am having issues as pressing the tab key doesnt cycle through the text fields when the app screen is not maximised.

I have 8 Textfields arranged in a Gridview and when the app screen is maximised the tab key moves through the fields as expected, left to right then down. When I reduce the screen size the tab key only cycles 2 fields in a continuous loop. How can I get this working properly?
Code as shown:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text("Test App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child:Container(
      height: 180,
      // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      child: GridView.count(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      childAspectRatio: 5,
      children:  [
      buildColumn(context,txt: "A"),
        buildColumn(context,txt: "B"),
        buildColumn(context,txt: "C"),
        buildColumn(context,txt: "D"),
        buildColumn(context,txt: "E"),
        buildColumn(context,txt: "F"),
        buildColumn(context,txt: "G"),
        buildColumn(context,txt: "H"),
      ])
    )
      )
    );
  }

    Column buildColumn(BuildContext context,{txt}) {
      return Column(children: [
    Text(txt),
    Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
    width: 300,
    child:TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black12, width: 1.0),
      ),),)
    ),
        ]
  );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, but it can be fixed by adding `focusedBorder` (either removing `enabledBorder`):

```dart
        child: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12, width: 1.0)),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1.0)),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks yes I believe its a bug. I tried your answer and it only works well if I completely remove enabledBorder & focusedBorder.  With both, or just the focused border, it seems to work when its just Textfields but when I change one of the Textfields, for example G to a dropdown button the tab order gets messed up again